# EF Transaction max time out not enough

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, transactionscope

i am using transaction scope with entity framework. I did some configuration for transaction timeout. I don't find error where it is. when i want to do some insert i do that but in loop index:83 i get "Underlying provider cannot open" error. I think transaction has time out.

```
TransactionOptions transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
                transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;
                transactionOptions.Timeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;

                using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
                {
```

app.config

```
<system.transactions>
            <defaultSettings timeout="03:00:50" />
        </system.transactions>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `TransactionScope`'s timeout it won't change the underlying resources' timeouts (SQL).

It seems you're using Entity framework, in that case, if you want to change the EF timeout, do this (EF6):

```
this.context.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
```

This timeout cannot obviously be greater than the one set on `TransactionOptions`.

Keep in mind that your transactionss should take as little time as possible (long runnning processes can cause locking on the DB).